# Dialog in c++,win32

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am  using win32 c++ ,So I want to create dialog, "Message Box, Color Dialog" and it works but the problem I had that when I call that dialog it won't be shown till minimize the parent window and the maximize it again. here is a simple of color dialog

```
COLORREF choseColor()
{
    CHOOSECOLOR color;
    COLORREF ccref[16];
    COLORREF selcolor=0x000000;

    memset(&color,0,sizeof(color));
    color.lStructSize=sizeof(CHOOSECOLOR);
    color.hwndOwner=NULL;
    color.lpCustColors=ccref;
    color.rgbResult=selcolor;
    color.Flags=CC_RGBINIT;

    if(ChooseColor(&color))
        {
        selcolor=color.rgbResult;
        }
    return selcolor;
}
```

Comment: Try adding CC_FULLOPEN to the Flags bit mask. Likewise, you may want to try setting the *parent* of that modal dialog.

Comment: @WhozCraig I try doing that but also same thing

Comment: You lost me at "and the minimize again".  Don't leave the hwndOwner at NULL, set it to the your main window handle.

Comment: @Hans Passant when I do like what you said it freeze the parent window and it does not show anything

Comment: It is supposed to "freeze" the parent window, ChooseColor() displays a dialog.  "Does not show anything" isn't otherwise easily guessable.